# Combinations with restrictions in a set

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Q1. Alex and Erin are two of the eight students trying out for a certain five-person chess team. If Alex and Erin must make it to the chess team, in how many different ways can the chess team be populated?

To solve for the above we can assume that two players Erin and Alex are already part of the chess team leaving us with 4 players to choose from 6 players. Hence 6C3

Q2.  In a treasure chest, there are five different flawed diamonds and three different perfect diamonds. If a pirate selects four diamonds from the chest, in how many ways can four diamonds be selected, if exactly two of them must be perfect diamonds?

In Q2 if I try to apply the same logic as of Q1 i.e. 2 diamonds must be perfect(I can assume them to be already selected) which would leave me to select 2 diamonds from five flawed diamonds which would be 5C2, but that's not the solution. What am I missing in here?

Comment: The chess team has five players, so you need to select three additional players, not four.

Comment: You also need to select the perfect diamonds. In the chess example, you have only 1 way to select Alex&Erin (to select them...)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Made the edit to the question

Comment: Your answer to the first question is now correct.

Comment: @YJT Does it have to do with the fact that in Q2 we are dealing with separate groups?

Comment: answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both questions you choose $a$ out of $A$ objects from one group and $b$ out of $B$ objects from the second group. In both cases, the answer is ${A \choose a}{B \choose b}$.

In Q1 $A=a=2$ so you don't see any term in the answer. In $Q2$ you see since $A=3$ and $a=2$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was only factoring in the 5C2 part for Q2 as I thought 2 perfect diamonds are already part of the selection(which I assumed for case 1) but looking at above for Q1 it basically leads on to 1 so is not observed separately,